CSP Header with ExtJS
I have a little problem with my application. I want to configure a CSP Header to counter all XSS potential vulnerabilities. But I have this error :
Uncaught EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP
    DomQuery http://localhost/lib/js/extjs/pkgs/ext-core.js:21
    <anonymous> http://localhost/lib/js/extjs/pkgs/ext-core.js:21

This is my configuration :
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'"

Do you have a solution please ? Thanks u !
I try to add unsafe eval but it is not secure..

EDIT
I want to do with unsafe-eval but with not unsafe-inline, do you have some recommandation to add the JS script ? I saw nonce but it is not a option because I cannot modify the code for this feature, I want to use Hashes but it is a bit difficult no ?

You can try to work with nonce; But you have to add it to index.html microloader script and to bootstrap::1317. I did not fully test it, but that should help as a first step.

If possible you can rewrite the eval statements as described in https://web.dev/articles/csp#unsafe-eval.
If this is not possible your options are to replace/remove the component that has eval or use 'unsafe-eval'. This weakens your policy, but even a policy allowing 'self', 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' is better than no policy as attackers can't load additional scripts and can't exfiltrate data.

Yes but I have a XSS in the application and when I add unsafe-eval, the XSS is effective..
